# PowerShell - Set Alias for Loaded Assembly

Tags: .net, powershell

I use this code to load a *.Net* assembly to PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") | out-null 
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello world")
```

Can I set an alias for an assembly (for example: 'System.Windows.Forms' = 'Forms') so that I don't have to type the assembly's full name when calling a static methods like MessageBox.Show()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't create some sort of namespace alias per se, you can use the following trick (taken from Lee Holmes' PowerShell Cookbook):

```
$namespace = "System.Windows.Forms.{0}"
$form = New-Object ($namespace -f "Form")
```

But that only will work with `New-Object` since that takes a string for the class name. You can't use that syntax with a type name in square brackets.

What you *can* do, however, is leave out the `System` part which is implied:

```
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World!")
```

Makes it slightly shorter.

Comment: I didn't know about System being implied.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kleinux: It works for referring to types, which is why you can write `[datetime]` instead of `[system.datetime]` but it won't work for loading an assembly (that is, `Add-Type -Assembly Windows.Forms` won't work).

Comment: Actually, "System" is **not** implied -- it is just part of the search path. Quoting from "Windows PowerShell in Action": "Type resolution -- When PowerShell resolves a type name, it first checks the type name alias table;
then it checks to see whether a type exists whose full name matches the string
specified. Finally it prepends the type with system. and checks to see whether a
type exists that matches the new string. This means things that are in the System
namespace look like they might be aliased."  There's more but space here is limited.

Answer (score 16):

You can store the type in variable and use the variable

```
$forms = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]
$forms::Show('Hello')
```

And in this case you can load the assembly like this:

```
Add-Type –assembly system.windows.forms
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/73070)'s answer you can use this function to set "aliases" to assemblies. It basically assigns an assembly to a function with the name of the given alias you want.

```
function Global:Add_Assembly_Alias($STR_assembly, $alias) {

    [string]$assembly = "$STR_assembly.{0}"
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("
            function Global:$alias(`$namespace) {
                [string](`"$assembly`" -f `$namespace)
            }
        ")
    )
}
```

E.g. if you want to assign System.Windows.Forms to wforms you would call the main function as

```
Add_Assembly_Alias System.Windows.Forms wforms
```

It generates you the function called "wforms" with namespace as argument which you can use to add new objects etc. If you want to add for example a textbox object you would just have to call

```
$tb = new-object (wforms TextBox)
```

It is not much, but I think this is as close as you can get to assign an assembly to something similar to an alias. Unfortunately I didn't manage to impelement this for the direct calls of the form

```
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World!")
```

but I hope this still helps.

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 1):

You can add Powershell type accelerator (alias for type):

```
$accel = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accel::add("mb","System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox")
[mb]::Show("Hello world")
```

More details can be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/09/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators/) and [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-Type-Accelerators-to-b59908eb#content).

WIth PowerShell 5 you can also import namespaces:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[MessageBox]::Show("Hello world")
```