# Looking for BP on PS using module, import-module, import using dot-sourcing and Add-PSSnapin

Tags: powershell, include

Background: I am looking for Best Practices for building PowerShell framework of my own. As I was used to be .NET programmer I like to keep source files small and organize code in classes and libraries.

Question: I am totally confused with `using module`, `import-module`, sourcing using dot-import and `Add-PSSnapin`. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it does not. Some includes work when running from ISE/VS2015 but fail when running via cmd `powershell -command "& './myscript.ps1'"`. I want to include/import classes and functions. I also would like to use type and namespace aliases. Using them with includes produces even weirdest results, but sometimes somehow they work.

**Edit: let me be more specific:**

Local project case (all files in one dir): main.ps1, common_autorun.ps1, _common.psm1, _specific.psm1.

How to include these modules into main script using relative paths?

_specific.psm1 also rely on _common.psm1.

There are `ScriptBlocks` passed between modules that may contain calls to classes defined in parent context.

common_autorun.ps1 contains solely type accelerators and namespace imports as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38919605/2746150).

Modules contain mainly classes with static methods as I am not yet used to PowerShell style of programming where functions do not have predicted returns.

As I understand my problems are related to `context` and `scope`. Unfortunately these PowerShell concepts are not well documented for v5 classes.

**Edit2: Simplified sample:**

_common.psm1 contains [watch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38976626/2746150)

_specific.psm1 contains [getDiskSpaceInfoUNC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158640/2746150)

main.ps1 contains just:

```
watch 'getDiskSpaceInfoUNC "\\localhost\d$"'
```

What includes/imports should I put into these files in order this code to work both in ISE and `powershell.exe -command "& './main.ps1'"`?

Of cause this works perfectly when both functions are defined in main.ps1.

Comment: Add-PSSnapin, dot-sourcing and Import-Module are different mechanisms to accomplish different things (although Import-Module and dot-sourcing overlaps depending on input). Without examples of these "weirdest results" it's hard to provide an explanation

Comment: You have forgot to mention `using module` which can be used to accomplish yet another things apparently. Providing "weirdest results" is hard as there are so many of them and not all of them repeatable,